# Are the reversed digits of $\pi$ equidistributed modulo 1?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Let $r_n$ be the real number obtained by truncating the decimal expansion of $\pi$ at $n$ total digits, removing the decimal point, reversing the digits, then prepending a new decimal point. For example, $r_3$ is computed as follows: $$\pi \approx 3.14 \to 314 \to 413 \to .413.$$
Here are the first few values of $r_n$:

\begin{align*}
    r_1 &= .3 \\
    r_2 &= .13 \\
    r_3 &= .413 \\
    r_4 &= .1413 \\
    r_5 &= .51413.
\end{align*}

Is $\{r_n\}$ equidistributed on the unit interval $[0, 1]$? That is, is it true that $$\lim_n \frac{|\{r_1, \dots, r_n\} \cap [a, b]|}{n} = b - a$$ for all $0 \leq a \leq b \leq 1$?

Comment: Little is known about the digits of $\pi$.  It is perfectly possible (if highly improbable) that from some point on, only two digits appear.  Of course, it is conjectured that this is not the case but, as I say, nothing is really known.

Comment: To elaborate on @lulu, the answer to your question is probably yes, but a proof (especially here) is highly unlikely.

Comment: Ah, I was worried that this might be the case. I hoped that something like Weyl's criterion or the equidistribution theorem would apply here. Thanks for the heads-up!